# How to convert a grouped pandas series to a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The `df` below contains integers grouped by time. I’m trying to convert these to a `numpy` array.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],        
    'A' : [3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 1, 6, 7], 
    'B' : [2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2, 6, 5],                           
})

GA = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['A'].apply(np.array))
```

Intended Out:

```
[[ 3  4  5]
 [ 2  5  6]
 [ 1  6  7]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use to to list before converting

```
np.array(df.groupby('Time')['A'].apply(list).tolist())
```

Out:

```
array([[3, 4, 5],
   [2, 5, 6],
   [1, 6, 7]])
```